# Best way to get know which node deleted in a linked list?

Tags: java, linked-list

I came across a question like, how to get know which node was deleted in a linked list.
for example : there is a linked list which conatins several nodes and the linked list passed to a 
function which will delete an arbitary node and will return the list back.. is there any way get 
to know which node got deleted.

as per my view before passing the linked list we need to mantain an array which will conatin all 
the addresses of each node of the list and after deleted we need to traverse and find out which node got deleted.

what is the best way.

Ex:

```
public class GetDeletedNode{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        LinkedList<String> ll = new LinkedList<String>();
        ll.add("a");
        ll.add("b");
        ll.add("c");
        ll.add("d");

        ll = deleteArbitaryNode(ll);

        //write code to get know which node got deleted.
        //
        //code goes here


        for(String str:ll){
            System.out.println(str);
        }
    }

    private static LinkedList<String> deleteArbitaryNode(LinkedList<String> ll) {       
        //delete arbitary node
        Random random = new Random();
        ll.remove((int)((long)3*random.nextDouble()+1));
        return ll;      
    }
}
```

Comment: why don't you just return the removed item from method ?

Comment: @JigarJoshi:Why is this not an answer?

Comment: the trick of the question is like that, the arbitrary delete method will not change but we need to figure it out in the main method.. as per my view before passing the linked list we need to mantain an array which will conatin all the addresses of each node of the list and after deleted we need to traverse and find out which node got deleted.  i need a better answer?

Answer (score 0):

The call to 'public E remove(int index)' provides the object removed.

So ... replace your code like this and return the node removed to the caller:

```
public class GetDeletedNode{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        LinkedList<String> ll = new LinkedList<String>();
        ll.add("a");
        ll.add("b");
        ll.add("c");
        ll.add("d");

       // removes the random node and then returns it

        String removeObject  = deleteArbitaryNode(ll);

        for(String str:ll){
            System.out.println(str);
        }
    }

    private static T deleteArbitaryNode(LinkedList<T> ll) {       
        //delete arbitary node
        Random random = new Random();
        return ll.remove((int)((long)3*random.nextDouble()+1));      
    }
}
```

You may also want to re-work your random node chooser to something that uses the size() in List ans then it can be used with any size list.

Comment: thanks for your answer but the questions trick is that we should not return the deleted node or index.. but we have to figure it out which one got deleted .. please go through the question detailed.. not the code (it is for reference only)